# Refresh Parent LWC on button Submit

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, refreshapex

Please read me out before marking my question as duplicate :pray

I have a situation where I want to refresh my parent LWC on submit button.
I have created an event to communicate from my child component to parent component.
My event is working properly but I am not sure how to refresh the component.
I dont want to use `window.reload` where it refreshes entire web.

I have tried using `refreshApex` but it only refreshes the my details page and related lists not my component.
I have tried `this.template.querySelector('[data-id]=myid').innerHTML.reload;`
I have tried `$A.eval('e.force:refresh')`
**(Please ignore the syntax)**

Below is my code snippet what I have tried.

childCompnent.js

```
const recordInput = { apiName: CaseIssue_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };

    createRecord(recordInput)
      .then((data) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('success', detail: this.orderItem.product_id));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.postError = true;
      });
```

parentComponent.html

```
<div data-id={item.product_id}>
    <c-order-line-item delivery-id={delivery.delivery_id}
                      order-item={item} currency-code={currencyCode}
                      show-warning={showWarning}
                      case-issues={caseIssues}
                      onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    </c-order-line-item>
</div>
```

parentComponent.js

```
handleSuccess(event) {
   let productId = event.detail;
   this.template.querySelector('[data-id=$productId]').innerHTML.reload;
}
```

I have tried several ways to refresh it but its only refreshing record page and related lists
[image]

I want to refresh the green part where my component is, but after running this its only refreshing the blue highlighted part.
It would be really great if someone can help here :pray

Comment: It's a prerelease feature but if you are using the @wire feature and the Lightning Data Service than this should help you with your issue:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm​

Comment: @NinaRosen Thanks for quick response. I am not using @ wire and LDS here. Its API callout on submit button therefore I cannot use wire or LDS .

Comment: Maybe this article helps you:

https://medium.com/@amitsalesforce.com/lightning-web-components-lwc-events-communicate-with-events-85bd325f71b4